# Bitmap Image not loading (Blank)

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I have this issue with loading my Bitmap image. I created a custom ImageAdapter and ImageItem for my GridLayout view. The application is supposed to take a picture, save it to the external storage, and retrieve the image from the external storage, showing it as a small thumbnail in a grid. When that image is clicked from the grid, a new Activity is started, showing the full-sized image. Everything has worked fine so far (The images get saved, and I can actually view them on the file system, the supplied path is correct), but the problem I am facing is that when I load the image, it shows up blank in the GridView, and when it is clicked upon, the new Activity also shows a blank image. I would greatly appreciate any help I can get! Here's the code:

The getView for the custom Adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null){
            final ImageItem imageItem = (ImageItem) getItem(position);
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);

            final TextView nameView = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.nameView);
            nameView.setText(imageItem.getName());

            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            String url = imageItem.getUrl();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(url);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            imageView.setPadding(PADDING, PADDING, PADDING, PADDING);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

            return itemLayout;
        } else {
            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Comment: first of all, you need to bind bitmap to image view even if convertview == null. Otherwise you will get always the same picture.The second, what is in your url? does it internet url or file or smth else?

Comment: @Demand, It is a file. Thanks for your response!